# Поправить подсказку в пункте "Мне необходимо добавить или удалить способы входа" контактной формы

Tags: дефект, предложение, статус-завершено, контактная-форма

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/contact. Выбрать "Мне необходимо добавить или удалить способы входа".

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1. Ссылка ведёт просто на страницу профиля. А нужно хотя на страницу настроек: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/preferences
2. Не правом верхнем углу, а в левом нижнем.
3. Добавить способы входа -> Доступ.

   > [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На MSE ([Fix text in message box on contact page for "How to add or remove login credentials" item](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/323633/260198)) квалифицировали как [дефект](/questions/tagged/%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%84%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82) с комментарием:

> The "my logins" link used to be at the top right of your profile page.
>   That popup just hasn't been updated in a very long time. ;) That may
>   be contributing to why we get so many requests asking how to do this
>   simple task

Comment: Как я понимаю, это не относится к локализации, так как ссылка в движке на всех сайтах одна. Верно? Если да, то ждем правки и ответа на MSE!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky ссылка да, а вот перевод можно и поменять пока.

Comment: Если я верно понимаю, переводы должны быть на Traducir (Transifex).

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky https://ru.traducir.win/string/8950 добавил перевод, нужно заапрувить.

Comment: Спасибо! (Готово!)